# Git status doesn't show changes but git diff does

Tags: git

In order to be able to change the branch in Git, I had to stage all modified files. Once I did this, I could change the branch. However, now if I do a `git status` it doesn't detect the changes, but if I do a `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` or `git diff HEAD^` the changes are shown. How can I recover from this? :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only you have staged the modified files, but it seems that you also created a commit. `HEAD^` refers to the commit that is the first parent of `HEAD`, and `HEAD` is the current commit, usually the tip of the branch.  So `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` shows the diff of the last commit. That is similar to the patch that is shown by `git show HEAD`. `git diff HEAD^` shows the diff between your working tree and the tree that corresponds to `HEAD^`, and that should be equivalent to `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` if you have not made any modification to your working tree since the last commit.

If you want to go back, and "cancel" your last commit, you can use the following command:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

That will reset the current branch to `HEAD^`, without modifying your working tree.

Comment: I've edited my question, running `git diff HEAD^` also shows the changes. So, I have a big problem now :(

Comment: @Caumons: I have edited my answer. I am not sure I have really understood what you mean by "recover from this". What is your problem, exactly? You did commit your changes, so what is the problem? :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Irineau! I've done a `git reset HEAD^` and now running `git status` shows the changes again!